# Strange behavior of I() in left-/right-hand side of formula

Tags: r, formula

```
set.seed(98234)
y <- rnorm(100)
x <- rnorm(100)
lm0 <- lm(y ~ x)
lm1 <- lm(I(y) ~ I(x))
```

all work perfectly fine and I guess we can agree that ´lm0´ is what one would expect to happen. `lm1` is equal to `lm0` (judging by coefficients). So are

```
set.seed(98234)
lm3 <- lm(I(rnorm(100)) ~ rnorm(100))
set.seed(98234)
lm4 <- lm(rnorm(100) ~ I(rnorm(100)))
```

But when `I()` is on neither or both sides of the formula I don't get the results from above:

```
set.seed(98234)
lm2 <- lm(I(rnorm(100)) ~ I(rnorm(100)))
set.seed(98234)
lm5 <- lm(rnorm(100) ~ rnorm(100))
```

Any ideas why?

Comment: I suspect that, in fact, none of those things are doing what you think they are. Save the results in each case to something like `m` and then look at `terms(formula(m))` in each case.

Answer (score 1):

The left side of the argument is never broken down into components, thus the `I` grouping symbol is unnecessary.

```
lm(I(a+b+c+d/e)~f)
```

Would be the same as

```
lm(a+b+c+d/e~f)
```

Whereas

```
lm(a~b+c+d/e)
```

Would NOT be the same as

```
lm(a~I(b+c+d/e))
```

Or even

```
lm(a~b+c+I(d/e))
```

Comment: I was aware of this, but I don't understand why using `I()` on just one side works, but using it on both sides doesn't (I've edited the question for clarity).